# jquery add input type image on select if selected and remove if not

Tags: jquery, select

I need to add an input type image on a select. There's no drop down just a scroll bar. I want to image to appear when an option is selected and then remove it when not selected. It's more like a want than a need though...Hahaha

For example:

I have this select tag..

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value=1>TEXT ONE</option>
    <option value=2>TEXT TWO</option>
</select>
```

I want to be like this when I select one of the two options..

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value=1><input type=image src="blah.png"/>TEXT ONE</option>
    <option value=2>TEXT TWO</option>
</select>
```

Then goes back to the original when not selected, not focused or nothing is selected at all..

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value=1>TEXT ONE</option>
    <option value=2>TEXT TWO</option>
</select>
```

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can nest input tags as such. What you could do is determine which one is selected with javascript and then add a class to the option tag which would then display an image in the background of the tag. You could use the `onChange="myfunction()"` attribute to fire a function when the options are changed. But I don't believe that all versions of IE support the background on an option tag.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification, I've tried a simple select and with input on it's options. The input either isn't shown or moves out of the select. haha